# White spots on indoor palms

Tags: indoors, palm

Can someone help identify the white mildewy stuff growing on my indoor palms and how to possibly get rid of them? Tried wiping them down with mild soap water, but didn't seem to help much. Thank you.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

This is an advanced case of [mealy bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mealybug).  They can hide in the axils of the new growth and are hard to get rid off.

You can try soap and water or neem applied three times at five day intervals.

In cases like this where the pest is well established sometimes it is more effective to get rid of the plant before the problem spreads to other plants.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I would remove dead stems and brown fronds -- they are not only unsightly, but can provide a place for the critters to hide.

Comment: Hi Greg, can you add more detail about the critters, what are they, how can they be controlled....